# Why the final color value is the product of two other color values in shader program?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

in the diffuse lighting model or other models,the final color value of a pixel should be a product of other two light color value,and i don't quite understand.
like this:

```
float4 c;
c.rgb = (s.Albedo * _LightColor0.rgb*diff);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you also need to consider the colour of the lights and those reflected from the surrounding.

In the code you have submitted `s.Albedo` is the colour of the object itself and `_LightColor0.rgb` provides the colour of your main light (that is the directional Light in your scene). as an experiment first try changing the colour of your main light from white to red to blue and you will notice what happens.

Also without the `_LightColor0.rgb * diff` multiplied the object will give flat colours and look more like a 2D object.

Comment: thanks for your reply.And does that mean when I combine different colors,i just simply multiply them together?

Comment: You can also achieve some different results by adding and subtracting or performing some other mathematical operation on the colours. But when you need to give some Light effect you will need to multiply it.

Comment: But I think multiply means the final color is darker than any other source colors in most cases.Shouldn't it be brighter when two colors are combined?

Comment: Have a look at following link. It has a very good explanation of color maths in shaders.
http://www.laurenscorijn.com/articles/colormath-basics

Comment: Thank you very much,you helped me a lot.